# using mkdir and touch sub-processes sequentially doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix

I have an error that I keep encountering repeatedly, sadly without being able to find solution to at the site.

```
try:
    #create working dir if it doens't exist already
    if not os.path.isdir(WORKINGDIR):
        print '>>>mdkir ',WORKINGDIR
        subprocess.Popen(['mkdir',WORKINGDIR]).wait()
        print os.path.isdir(WORKINGDIR)

    #create output csv file
    outputCSVFile = WORKINGDIR+ '/'+'results.csv'
    if not os.path.isfile(outputCSVFile):
        print '>>> touch',outputCSVFile
        subprocess.check_output(['touch',outputCSVFile])
```

Although the line: `print os.path.isdir(WORKINGDIR)` always prints `True`, `subprocess` returns this error:

> touch: cannot touch
>   `/nfs/iil/proj/mpgarch/archive_06/CommandsProfiling/fastScriptsOutput190916/results.csv':
>   No such file or directory

The same error doesn't appear when I use `subprocess.checkoutput` instead of `subprocess.Popen().wait()`.
I know that this issue can be solved in many ways (such as using `os` methods to creates directories and files), but I am interested on why my way isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: as some suggested, the problem probably lies with the fact that the program continues too fast after the `subprocess.Popen`, and hence the issue is solved using `subprocess.checkoutput` which is probably slower (since it has to wait for output). But still - I don't understand exactly what is happening, since `os.path.istdir` shows that the dir was created, before continuing to the line that performs `touch`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a race condition caused by caching somewhere along the line. Perhaps the directory create is deferred for a fraction of a second. Perhaps the streaming of output via `subprocess.checkoutput` causes just enough delay to cause the directory to be created. Simple check would be to add an intentional wait in the broken version and see if that fixes it. Of course, I can't say for sure that the methods aren't invoking the shell differently and you're experiencing an edge-case. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can field that one

Comment: I believe that you are right, and that this is what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have file permission problems. 
In your path it appears that you are using NFS. Did you already try it on the local file system?

Anyway, you should avoid to use sub processes for simple file operations.

To create a directory:

```
if not os.path.exists(WORKINGDIR):
    os.makedirs(WORKINGDIR)
```

For touch:

```
import os

def touch(fname, times=None):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)

touch(WORKINGDIR+ '/'+'results.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm afraid that permissions is not the issue here. As you can see the directory created successfully, and the touch command works ok when the directory is created before, or when I use subprocess.check_output(). I am interested on why my code doesn't work properly with Popen.